# Full Disk Encryption, Single User System: User/Root Passwords required?

Tags: passwords, disk-encryption

Are there any security issues of having no (or weak) passwords for user and root account on a single user system with full disk encryption (except boot partition)? Assuming no SSH server is running, or SSH is only valid using authentication keys.

Answer (score 2):

In modern versions of windows and most `*nix` distributions you typically run with lower level privileges and then elevate your privileges ("run as" / UAC / `sudo` / etc.) to do more risky tasks. In some cases there is just a prompt, but a more secure configuration would require the password each time you elevate.

If a malicious script or malware runs and want the hire privileges, the password can act as a gate. If you are always running as root or Administrator without a password, malicious software or scripts may just run commands on their own.

Full Disk Encryption only protects the data when the system is off; when the system is live the data is plainly accessible. The password or key you use for FDE serves a different purpose from operating system and user passwords. You can choose not to have a password on user accounts, but the FDE doesn't really protect against the same types of threats.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question depends on the threats you're fighting against.

If you're only concern is other people stealing your system, your're fine by using FDE as this prevents them from even getting to the point where they could attack the password. This assumes that your boot-password is strong and you power your machine down often.

However, if you think malware is a threat (which it certainly is) you should set a good root-password  to prevent malware from uploading the password file, cracking it and then attacking your system, as they have now gotten root-access and can do many bad things with no problems.